Approximating country by rectangles
Say I have a list of coordinates (these form the border of a country) called testpolycoords that is about 400 points long. I want to use a quadtree to divide the polygon's bounding box in 4 rectangles and check if any are entirely contained in the polygon. If so, they get saved, and if not they are divided again and rechecked. Any new rectangles which become disjoint from the polygon are also discarded.
I want to repeat this process to a certain degree of accuracy in area, but even for demanding that they lie within 50% of each other, my code is very slow. I've attached it below. Is there any issues which you think makes it go so slowly?
testpoly = Polygon[testpolycoords]
initialbox = BoundingRegion[testpolycoords, "MinRectangle"]

Split4[x_] := {Rectangle[{x[[1, 1]], x[[1, 2]]}, RegionCentroid[x]], 
  Rectangle[{x[[2, 1]], x[[2, 2]]}, RegionCentroid[x]], 
  Rectangle[{x[[2, 1]], x[[1, 2]]}, RegionCentroid[x]], 
  Rectangle[{x[[1, 1]], x[[2, 2]]}, RegionCentroid[x]]}

testlist = {initialbox};
floatlist = {};
finallist = {};

ttt = 1;
approxarea = Area[initialbox];

While[Abs[truearea - approxarea]/truearea > .5, floatlist = {}; 
 For[j = 1, j <= Length[testlist], j++, 
  floatlist = Flatten[Append[floatlist, Split4[testlist[[j]]]]]];
 testlist = floatlist;
 For[k = 1, k <= Length[testlist], k++, 
  If[RegionWithin[testpoly, testlist[[k]]] == True, 
   finallist = Flatten[Append[finallist, testlist[[k]]]]; 
   testlist[[k]] = xxx, 
   If[RegionDisjoint[testpoly, testlist[[k]]] == True, 
    testlist[[k]] = xxx]]]; testlist = DeleteCases[testlist, xxx];
 If[Length[finallist] != 0, 
  approxarea = Area[RegionUnion[Flatten[{testlist, finallist}]]], 
  approxarea
   = approxarea]; ttt++;
 floatlist = {}; Print[ttt]]

Note that ttt is just counting the number of times we divided. Furthermore, the final approximation will be the RegionUnion[Flatten[{testlist,finallist}].

I wouldn't use any of the Region functions because they're slow. I'd rasterize it to a b/w image first and use that.

Here is a brute force method that has no accuracy check like your "lie within 50% of each other", which I didn't understand. If you can clarify what your accuracy check is, this can be optimized.
(* Setting up some test data. *)
usaPoly = First@Cases[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"][EntityProperty["Country", "Shape"]], _Polygon, Infinity];
initialbox = BoundingRegion[usaPoly, "MinRectangle"];

Graphics[{Blue, initialbox, Black, usaPoly}]


(* A function to divide a rectangle into 4 sub-rectangles. *)
RefineRectangle[rect_Rectangle] := 
  Rectangle @@@ Tuples[{MeshCoordinates[rect], {RegionCentroid[rect]}}];

(* The function that chooses what to do with a rectangle based on the given region. *)
KeepDropRefine1[region_?RegionQ][poly_Rectangle] :=
  Which[
    RegionWithin[region, poly], poly,
    RegionDisjoint[region, poly], Nothing,
    True, Splice[RefineRectangle[poly]]];

(* We continue mapping this function over our list of rectangles until no more changes occur. *)
AbsoluteTiming[
  result = FixedPoint[Map[KeepDropRefine1[usaPoly]], {initialbox}, 7];
  Length@result]
(* {48.0557, 1856} *)

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, White}], result}]


So, it took 48 seconds to create 1856 rectangles with a limit of 7 iterations for the FixedPoint (so, we probably don't have an acceptable set of rectangles yet in terms of all being inside the region). Many rectangles are checked many times, so there are optimizations we could do even before we add your accuracy checks.

What is RefineRectangle in the code?

@cvgmt Thanks for the heads up. copy-paste error.

@cvgmt Fixed.....

This is excellent, thank you very much! By my accuracy check, I calculated the area of the approximation at each step and demanded the loop run until it got within a margin of the true area.
